# Categorization of Lewin's Work

Tags: social-psychology, psychology, dynamic-systems, gestalt-psychology

I'm trying to categorize [Kurt Lewin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Lewin)'s work, specifically his force field model and his three-step model of change.

From what I read, he was strongly influenced by the Gestaltists and he's considered the father of social psychology.  However, the Gestaltists, as far as I understand it, were mostly concerned with perception and the above models are developmental and/or social.  The category of social psychology is a bit broad though---there are vastly different approaches in that category.

Would it be fair to say that Lewin took the Gestaltists' notion that the whole is more than the parts and applied it to social systems in which the system is more than the individuals, that he took the idea from psychodynamics that individuals aren't atomic wholes but really systems of integrated but often warring forces, and that he used the concepts of dynamic systems theory to describe how inner- and intra-personal forces settle into semi-stable equilibria?

(I appreciate any type of source, but citeable ones would be really great.)